# Checking object access using ActionFilters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I have been happily using a BaseController class with a custom ActionFilterAtribute, overriding OnActionExecuting(). I use this BaseController class for all my controllers as a convenient way of checking the id route value when it is passed in to the Controller.

This worked fine... I check for an id value, and if it exists I check to see the controller name which determines the type of object that the id belongs to.

But then... I started to get errors which are created when a PartialView is called in ControllerB and presenting the same id in the FilterContext that was used for the parent Controller/View. For example say I have a url of localhost/Project/Details/5 where Project is the controller and Details the action with an id=5. Controller "Notes" gets called due to a PartialView and my ActionFilter is triggered this time for Controller "Notes" and the original "Project" id. The user is permitted access to ProjectId=5 but not NoteId=5

I hope this makes sense - I am struggling to explain. I now need to either find some way of ignoring the PartialView, or handling it, or using a different approach altogether. My end goal is to be able to check object access in my application based on the id of an object. Is there a "best approach" for this kind of problem? Maybe I need to write a filter for every controller? Or possibly check the Action name as well so I know when to ignore "id"?

My BaseController...

```
public class AccessCheckAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        int id;

        if (filterContext.RouteData.Values["id"] != null)
        {
            if (int.TryParse(filterContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString(), out id))
            {
                SPTdb db = new SPTdb();

                switch (filterContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString().ToLower())
                {
                    case "project":
                        project = db.Projects.Find(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem can be solved by using SQL query. You pass the table name and also with [key/value] of your object identity.